# Ruby Case Statements with Multiple conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, switch-statement, case-statement

I have a method that returns image size based upon the users selection and now I want to add another condition to my case statement. It is not setting the correct image size when I call the method again after my system call doing `pdfinfo` if the user chose `STANDARD` it should be `1250x1075` but it does not even do my case statement, it directly goes to `else` and sets `1728x1075`

This is what I've tried

```
205   def FaxCall.set_image_size(resolution, pdf_size=nil)
206     case resolution
207     when STANDARD && (pdf_size != LEGAL_PDF_SIZE)]
208       image="1728x1075"
209     when FINE && pdf_size != LEGAL_PDF_SIZE
210       image="1728x2150"
211     when SUPERFINE && pdf_size != LEGAL_PDF_SIZE
212       image="1728x4300"
213     when [STANDARD, (pdf_size === LEGAL_PDF_SIZE)]
214       image="1250x1720"
215     when FINE && pdf_size == LEGAL_PDF_SIZE
216       image="1700x2800"
217     when SUPERFINE && pdf_size == LEGAL_PDF_SIZE
218       image="3400x5572"
219     else
220       image="1728x1075"
221     end
222     return image
223   end
```

This is where I call my method

```
135    def FaxCall.prepare_doc(in_file,out_file,res=STANDARD)
139     image = FaxCall.set_image_size(res)
140     res = STANDARD unless RESOLUTION_OPTIONS.values.include?(res)
145       if ext.eql?("pdf")
146         pdf_size = `pdfinfo "#{in_file}"  | grep 'Page size:'`.gsub(/Page size:\s*\b/, '').chomp
147         if pdf_size == LEGAL_PDF_SIZE
148           image = FaxCall.set_image_size(res,pdf_size)
```

Comment: Readers may want to cut-and-paste your code to run it, with or without modification. To do so they must first remove the line numbers, which is a nuisance.  For that reason, please don’t include line numbers with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd create an array of hashes...

```
RES_MAP = [{res: STANDARD, legal: false, image: "1728x1075"},
  {res: FINE, legal: false , image: "1728x2150"},
  {res: SUPERFINE, legal: false , image: "1728x4300"},
  {res: STANDARD, legal: true, image: "1250x1720"},
  {res: FINE, legal: true , image: "1700x2800"},
  {res: SUPERFINE, legal: true , image: "3400x5572"}]
```

and then change `FaxCall.set_image_size(resolution, pdf_size=nil)` to look up the matching hash and grab the image size.

```
def FaxCall.set_image_size(resolution, pdf_size)
  is_legal = (pdf_size == LEGAL_PDF_SIZE)
  match_res = RES_MAP.select{ |r| r[:res] == resolution && r[:legal] == is_legal}.first
  return match_res.present? : match_res[:image] ? "1728x1075"
end
```

Easier to read and to add both more map values and extra criteria.

Comment: Why not make `RES_MAP` a hash with key-value pairs such as `[STANDARD, false] => "1728x1075"` or `{res: STANDARD, legal: false} => "1728x1075"`? You could then write, for example, `RES_MAP.fetch({res: STANDARD, legal: false}, "1728x1075")`. Key lookups would be a lot faster.

Answer (score 2):

`STANDARD && (pdf_size != LEGAL_PDF_SIZE)`, `FINE && pdf_size != LEGAL_PDF_SIZE`,  `SUPERFINE && pdf_size != LEGAL_PDF_SIZE`, `FINE && pdf_size == LEGAL_PDF_SIZE`, and `SUPERFINE && pdf_size == LEGAL_PDF_SIZE` are all booleans, but `resolution` is a `String`, so they will never match.

`[STANDARD, (pdf_size === LEGAL_PDF_SIZE)]` is an `Array`. An `Array` will never match a `String`.

So, therefore, none of your cases will ever match, and you will always fall into the `else` case.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `STANDARD` and `ELSE` have the same image size.

```
207     when STANDARD && (pdf_size != LEGAL_PDF_SIZE)]
208       image="1728x1075"
```

```
219     else
220       image="1728x1075"
```

See what I mean ?

Comment: I understand that but when it is ``STANDARD && pdf_size == LEGAL_PDF_SIZE`` it should return ``image = 1250x1720``

Answer (score 0):

@Jörg has explained the problem with your code. You might consider writing your method as follows.

```
DEFAULT_IMAGE_SIZE = "1728x1075"

def FaxCall.set_image_size(resolution, pdf_size=nil)
  case pdf_size
  when LEGAL_PDF_SIZE
    case resolution
    when STANDARD  then "1250x1720"
    when FINE      then "1700x2800"
    when SUPERFINE then "3400x5572"
    else                DEFAULT_IMAGE_SIZE
    end
  else
    case resolution
    when STANDARD  then "1728x1075"
    when FINE      then "1728x2150"
    when SUPERFINE then "1728x4300"
    else                DEFAULT_IMAGE_SIZE
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I received a downvote, suggesting a problem with my answer. (As usual, no accompanying explanation.) I would be grateful for a comment if a reader spots a problem.

Comment: I will just assume that readers saw your option right under the accepted answer and in comparison, it looked less advanced in case of scalability. But I personally think that your answer is more clear if that's the only sizes that will be used later.